# Customize back button on ActionBar (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

in my app i added back button on ActionBar but this is not visible properly because of dark theme of ActionBar. both ActionBar and back Button are black in color so back button is not visible.

i added this code in values.xml file

```
 <style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up</item>
</style>
```

and set.

```
minSdkVersion="14"
```

but it's not showing custom back buttom.

Answer (score 0):

In the res/values/styles.xml file put some custom style:

```
 <style name="AppThemeWithBackButton" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/actionbar_back_button</item>
 </style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
</style>

 <style name="TitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
 </style>
```

and use drawable/actionbar_back_button.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/back_icon" />
</layer-list>
```

and use drawable/actionbar_background.xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_color" />
</shape>
```

Above all code is regarding of customizing actinobar button and background. You can modify it as you want. Hope it will help you. Enjoy!!!